# How to display node's taxonomy child items in node using views for multiple parents

Tags: views, entities, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary with child terms

- term
- -child_term
- -child_term_1
- -child_term_2
- -term_1
- -child_term
- -child_term_1
- -child_term_2

Nodes have multiple parent terms assigned.

The goal is to display all parent and child terms in the exact node using views field.

I tried to implement it using taxonomy tree view with contextual filter (taxonomy term ID from the URL), but it displays only child terms for the first (one) parent item of the node.

Even view's "Preview with contextual filters" does not understand multiple contextual filter values with a "/"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal was to display child items for multiple taxonomy terms of the node in a node's field using views.

Solution:

---

1. Create content type with:

   1. Taxonomy term field (multiple values) - it's for parent items
   2. Views field - it's for displaying child items for ALL parents
2. Make standard taxonomy tree view with ajacency model (search google)

   1. Add a contextual filter with parent term ID

      1. Provide default value
      2. Taxonomy term ID from the URL
      3. filter to items that share any term
      4. When the filter value IS available or a default is provided

         1. Specify validation criteria - taxonomy term ID
         2. Filter value type - Ternm IDs separated by , or +
3. Edit view field of previously created content type

   1. Select the view created as a default value for this field
   2. From placeholder list select [node:field_bla_bla] (that's taxonomy parent field in the node) as an argument passed to default value

---

[image: How to display node's taxonomy child items in node using views for multiple parents]